# SQL Server / Oracle String Orderby Issue

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-order-by, oracle12c

I am noticing a difference between orderby handling in SQL Server (2014) and Oracle (12c). With respect to the screen shots/queries below, it appears there is a difference in the way Oracle and SQL Server handle the single quote character `'`. Since the ASCII value of quote is 39 which is less than ASCII value of 'A' which is 65, it appears to me that Oracle is doing the right thing.

QN: How can I make SQL Server behave the same way as Oracle or vice-versa in ordering the results

SQL Server Query:

```
select * 
from MyTable
order by ASSEMBLY_DESCRIPTION
```

SQL Server Result:

[image]

Oracle Query:

```
select * 
from MyTable
order by ASSEMBLY_DESCRIPTION
```

Oracle Results:

[image]

Comment: The two screenshots do not contain the same records.  Can you update your question?

Comment: What collation are you using in SQL Server?

Comment: check that both sql server and oracle is using similar collation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I just showed partial results in the original question to highlight the ordering issue

Comment: @DaleBurrell: I am new to both these databases. Would you be able to share how to check the collation in SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: [SQL Server Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/view-collation-information?view=sql-server-2017) - sorry no idea about oracle, but I'm sure google will help (how I found the SQL link)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

As Dale asked check the collation in use for the database.  Look for one that matches your desired output order and set it on the ORDER BY.  For example

```
order by column_name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Also if Unicode is in use the standard specifies certain sorting rules that can come into play.  Another option is to just accept the sort order produced by each product.